# How to have both credit card and Pay later option in webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm using Webform instead of the core module for a contribution because of conditionals and I don't succeed in finding a way to have the "pay later" option. I only see Stripe payment processor.
I tried the webform_Payment module but this is actually not what I need.
How do I do this?

I am using CiviCRM 5.12.3 on Drupal 7.66

Thanks!
Guillaume

Comment: Did you update the webform component for payment to include both options on the page?  (Just making sure we cross everything off the list before theorizing what else might be wrong.)

Comment: On the civi tab set the Payment method (?) field  to 'user selects'. then in the component you should be able to set it to static and just offer the two options you need

Comment: Thank you petednz, this is exactly what I was looking for! I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Guillaume - i will add as an Answer - pls Accept it and +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In webform, on the civi tab set the Payment Processor field to 'user selects'.

Then in the Payment Processor component you should be able to set it to static and just offer the two options you need.